# Array organization (C Programming)

Tags: c

As a beginner, I have come across an error in Visual Studio that I just can't figure out how to fix.

The following code is made to solve an array problem. The array would have duplicate values inside of it, thus, the program has to remove them and organize the remaining ones, as well as returning the new size of the array.

For example: `{1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 8}` ----> `{1, 2, 5, 6, 8}`.

The `cup` integer counts the `NULL`s in the unorganized array and, is used later on to switch between the values inside, for organization.

The errors I get are:

```
**Warning C4047 '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'**
```

and:

```
**Warning C4047 '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'**
```

On lines: `23`, `25`, `35` (I have added the line numbers in the code below).

```
void main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 8, 3 };
    int sizearr, i;

    sizearr = fixArr(a, sizeof(a));

    for (i = 0; i < sizearr; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int fixArr(int *ptr, int size) {

    int arrS1, arrS2, cup;

    for (arrS1 = 0; arrS1 < (size--); arrS1++) {

        for (arrS2 = (arrS1++); arrS2 < size; arrS2++) {
                           //23
            if (*(ptr + arrS1) = (ptr + arrS2)) {
                cup++; //25
                *(ptr + arrS2) = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    for (arrS1 = 0; arrS1 < cup; arrS1++) {

        for (arrS2 = 0; arrS2 < (size--); arrS2++) {
            // 35
            if (*(ptr + arrS2) = NULL) *(ptr + arrS2) = *(ptr + (arrS2++));
        }
    }
    return cup;
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are using the dereference operator * inconsistently.  Also it looks like you are using "=" when you probably mean "==".  "=" is an assignment, whereas "==" is a comparison.

Comment: Not only is this `if(*(ptr + arrS1) = (ptr + arrS2))` (line 23) not comparing like with like, it should have `==` not `=`. The mistake of `=` instead of `==` is repeated on line 35.

Comment: do you understand your own code?

Comment: @user132458 I hope so, 'cos I don't understand it.

Comment: `NULL` is to be assigned to pointers, to indicate that no address is stored in them, not to variables as you are doing in: `*(ptr + arrS2) = NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- `sizeof(a)` does not evaluate to the number of elements in `a`, but the size in bytes required for object `a`.  If `a` is an array, you can get the number of elements with `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`, but if `a` is a pointer, you cannot determine the number of elements from `a` alone.
- `NULL` is not a valid value for an `int`, you cannot use this method for an `int` array.
- Your comparisons are incorrect: you use the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`.
- You should declare the function `fixArr` before calling it from `main`.

Here is a simpler version that uses the *two finger method*: iterating with one index and storing unique elements into the same array with another index:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fixArr(int *ptr, int size) {
    int i;  // index for reading (first finger)
    int j;  // index for writing (second finger)
    int k;  // index for searching duplicates

    for (i = j = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            if (ptr[k] == ptr[i])
                break;
        }
        if (k == j) {  // element ptr[i] was not found
            ptr[j] = ptr[i];  // copy new unique element
            j++;       // increment new element count
        }
    }
    return j;  // new size
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 8, 3 };
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int i, newsize;

    printf("original array:");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    newsize = fixArr(a, size);

    printf("fixed array:");
    for (i = 0; i < newsize; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Reading your code I found quite a few mistakes, e.g. `sizeof(a)` doesn't return size of array, because in C there is no standard array type. Only memory allocated to a pointer. So in your case `sizeof(a)` returns size of pointer `a`. That's why you always have to keep track of the length of the array by yourself.

Back to your problem though. My simple solution would go like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int arr[] = {1,1,1,1,2,5,6,8,8,2,5,6,2,1,8,3};
    size_t len = 16;
    // create a new array with the same size as the original
    // since there is no guarantee all of the numbers
    // are not unique
    int *new_array = (int *)calloc(len, sizeof(int)), new_len = 0;

    // loop throught every number
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // if the current number, arr[i], is unique
        int unique = 1;
        // loop backwards to check if any of the previous
        // number are the same as the current one
        for (int j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
            // if the same number if found, set unique to 0
            // and break out of loop
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                unique = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if looped all the way to index 0 without
        // finding the same number, add it to the last index
        // of our new array and increment it's size
        if (unique) {
            new_array[new_len] = arr[i];
            new_len++;
        }
    }
    // finally, if there have been found any duplicated,
    // adjust the memory allocated to the new_array pointer
    if (new_len < len) {
        new_array = (int *)realloc(new_array, sizeof(int) * new_len);
    }

    // when you're done using your new array,
    // free the memory allocated to it
    free(new_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"`sizeof(a)` returns size of pointer `a`"*. No, `a` is not a pointer, it is an array so `sizeof a` gives (it is not a function so it does not return anything) the size of the array. To get the length of the array, use `(sizeof a / sizeof a[0])`.